# Why does the Visual Studio editor show dots in blank spaces?

Tags: visual-studio, formatting, whitespace, code-editor

I have a strange bug in the Visual Studio text editor.
All my blank spaces are replaced by a "."

```
public class Person
{
  int age;
}
```

looks like this

```
public..class..Person..........................
{..................
..int age;...................
}.....................
```

I reset the settings to default. Didn't work.
I also re-installed VS2008. Still didn't work.
What's the error?

Comment: btw, in this example would be 10x better keep the dots! 
The code is bad indented and these lost dots at the end of the line will probably create problem in the future when merging.

Answer (score 853, accepted):

Visual Studio is configured to show whitespace.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.

If you are using C# keyboard mappings: *(thanks Simeon)*

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>.

If you want to use the menu: *(thanks angularsen)*

```
Edit > Advanced > View White Space
```

Comment: Or Cntrl+E,S if you are using the C# Keyboard mappings.

Comment: Ah, that explains it! I'd tried to press Ctrl+E, D but missed and hit S instead... Thanks!

Comment: Did not work for me, I think Resharper addin intercepted both shortcuts described here. However, to uncheck Edit->Advanced->View whitespace solved it.

Comment: Thanks, this happens sometimes when clicking too fast (in the wrong window). It's already the third time I came here to look it up, thx

Comment: Works in VS2008. Cannot believe I randomly managed to press that combination!

Comment: @AndreasLarsen I think you should propose an edit to the answer here and add this as well. Knowing where the setting is is as helpful as the shortcut itself, and avoids problems like you described.

Comment: @julealgon: The answer with the second most votes already answers this.

Comment: in VS Version: 1.39.2 - 2019  view -> Render Whitespace

Answer (score 78):

Looks like you have the view white space option enabled.  Go to Edit -> Advanced -> and uncheck "View Whitespace"

Comment: Edit -> Advanced, not "View -> Advanced"

Comment: I am sorry, but I am unable to find Edit-> Advance as well.

Comment: @unknown, what version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: VS2008 is the version which i am using

Answer (score 27):

In Visual Studio 2012
Go to 

**`Edit -> Advanced -> View White Spaces`**
Or
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>

Answer (score 10):

~ FOR VISUAL STUDIO 6 ~

use: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>
to toggle on/off.

(or manualy go to: Edit> Advance > "View Whitespaces")

goodluck!

Works also for Visual Studio 2008, when 
   Tools/Options/Environment/Keyboard/Mapping Scheme: Visual C++ 6 
is selected.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and resolved by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>.

Answer (score 6):

Please press below buttons in combination of 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>W</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio vesrion `1.34.0` `View -> Toggle Render Whitespace`

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> followed by <kbd>S</kbd> key to remove the lines in Visual Studio 10

Answer (score 1):

go to **File -> Preferences -> Settings**, this will open two panels side by side, the left one is default setting and the right one is user setting, you can add your setting on right panel, for this you can add `"editor.renderWhitespace": "all"`.

Answer (score 0):

In `visual studio 2015`, `goto->view->formatting marks`, unselect `show`

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2019, this can also be configured in `Tools -> Options -> General -> View whitespace`