# Revert changes to UI in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I pressed a key that shows formatting in the IDE; I'd like to change it back to what it was before. How do I do that?

[image]

Comment: This is a duplicate, follow the link to find a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973571/why-does-the-visual-studio-editor-show-dots-in-blank-spaces

Answer (score 1):

it's probably "Edit->Advanced->View White space" which is toggled with CTRL+R CTRL+W

Answer (score 1):

Hahahahha :) - happened to me a while ago :D, very irritating!!

**Ctrl+Shift+8**

Comment: this site is simply awesome...not even one minute to get an answer...thx so much

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl-Shift-8.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Edit – Advanced – View White Space or Ctrl+R,Ctrl+W