# Visual studio 2010 formatting showing and I can't remove it

Tags: visual-studio-2010, formatting

It seems that stackoverflows image upload is broken in IE. http://imgur.com/HLbLe.png

Basically I have a bunch of text-formatting showing like - instead of spaces. I was pressing a keycombo and accidentally typed one and I don't know what it was.

How can I disable this? I've looked through all the options for Text Editor and couldn't find the right one.

Thanks everyone, the key combo I pressed was Ctrl-E+S. As I'm using c#

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973571/why-does-the-visual-studio-editor-show-dots-in-blank-spaces

Comment: You're right, I did a search but didn't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ctrl-R` + `Ctrl-W`

or

`Edit, Advanced, View Whitespace`

Answer (score 2):

The shortcut for this is "Ctrl+R, Ctrl+W".

You can look these things up in Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard. There is a search field there. In this case, if you type "whitespace" there, you'll quickly find the command.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit -> Advanced -> View White Space**

Answer (score 1):

It is not a text formatting option - it is simply displaying whitespace:

```
Edit – Advanced – View White Space
```

Or

<kbd>Ctrl + R + W</kbd>