# VS 2013 - change dashed lines formatting to casual white space

Tags: visual-studio-2013, editor

How can I can rid off those formatting option that draws dots every line?

[image: VS 2013]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the Visual Studio editor show dots in blank spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973571/why-does-the-visual-studio-editor-show-dots-in-blank-spaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CTRL + R, CTRL + W
```

Is the shortcut command to enable and disable "View White Space". Input them one after the other.