# How to disable the points in visual studio 2013 express in each line?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm not sure what I clicked on but I'm sure it was a mistake.

And now every line in my code is like this:

```
.............return list;
```

What should I click to remove all this green points before each line ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973571/why-does-the-visual-studio-editor-show-dots-in-blank-spaces

Comment: CTRL + R, CTRL + W will toggle between showing whitespaces as dots and not.

Comment: It's good to have the whitespace characters always displayed simply to check if you don't mix space and tab indentation, if you don't have trailing whitespace, etc. You can also check both using the Visual Studio extension.