# horizontal guide lines appeared on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio

I've noticed that all of a sudden the following lines have appeared in Visual Studio 2017 Professional:

[image: See here]

Does anyone know what they are and how to disable them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the Visual Studio editor show dots in blank spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973571/why-does-the-visual-studio-editor-show-dots-in-blank-spaces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate with : [Why does the Visual Studio editor show dots in blank spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973571/why-does-the-visual-studio-editor-show-dots-in-blank-spaces)

In short :

Visual Studio is configured to show whitespace.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.

If you are using C# keyboard mappings: *(thanks Simeon)*

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>.

If you want to use the menu: *(thanks angularsen)*

```
Edit > Advanced > View White Space
```